# WPF ListView with GridViewColumn and DataTemplate Code Behind

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I have ListView with GridView in WPF application. I have added couple of Gridviewcolumn in xaml which has celltemplate and DataTemplate using below code.

```
<GridView x:Name="DvGridView">
<GridViewColumn Header="Device Name" Width="200">
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding DeviceName}">
<TextBlock.Background>
 <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding DeviceColor}"/>
</TextBlock.Background>
  </TextBlock>

 </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn>
</GridView>
```

I would like to additional Gridviewcolumns in Code behind based on user selection. I tried below code

```
GridViewColumn nameColumn = new GridViewColumn();
nameColumn.Header = columnInfo;
nameColumn.Width = 120;

var text = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
text.SetValue(TextBlock.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Center);

Binding binding = new Binding("DeviceColor");
binding.Source = PmcDataInfoCollection;
SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush();
BindingOperations.SetBinding(brush, SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, binding);
text.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding(col));
text.SetBinding(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty, binding);

DataTemplate dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
dataTemplate.VisualTree = text;
nameColumn.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;
DvGridView.Columns.Add(nameColumn);
```

TextBlock.BackgroundProperty Binding of "DeviceColor" is not working fine. It always show in White color. Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: What is `PmcDataInfoCollection`? And why is there `SolidColorBrush brush`? It's apparently not used anywhere.

Comment: PmcDataInfoCollection is the DataContext which has property of DeviceColor. brush is used in binding. BindingOperations.SetBinding(brush, SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, binding);

Comment: `BindingOperations.SetBinding` obviously sets a Binding on `brush`, but what is `brush` used for later? In the code here it is entirely redundant and should be removed.

Comment: yes, but we need to bind that property to TextBlock.BackgroundProperty. Correct ?

Comment: See the answer please. As a note, when the DataContext already contains the PmcDataInfoCollection object, you don't need to set the Binding's Source property.

Answer (score 0):

Your are binding the `Color` property of a SolidColorBrush, but you are not actually using that Brush.

So instead of applying the Binding to the Background property of the TextBlock, just assign the Brush:

```
Binding binding = new Binding("DeviceColor");
binding.Source = PmcDataInfoCollection;

SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush();
BindingOperations.SetBinding(brush, SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, binding);

text.Background = brush;
```

In order to be able to apply the Binding directly to the Background property, you would need a converter that converts from Color to Brush:

```
text.SetBinding(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty,
    new Binding
    {
        Path = new PropertyPath("DeviceColor"),
        Source = PmcDataInfoCollection,
        Converter = new ColorToBrushConverter()
    });
```

The converter class:

```
public class ColorToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush((Color)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((SolidColorBrush)value).Color;
    }
}
```